# Varnish Cache: Specific Domain only NOT ALL

Tags: ubuntu, varnish-vcl

I need help. Is possible to cache a specific domain only, since I want not all domain to be cache, I want *example.com* only. Can I ask for configuration for it.. thanks in advance. I am using Varnish Cache 4.

I only have this

**/etc/varnish/default.vcl**

```
 backend marketics {
   .host = "127.0.0.1";
   .port = "7080";
 }
```

where my apache port is 7080 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `pass` for the other domains :

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (! req.host == "example.com") {
    return (pass);
  }
  #else failover to the default behaviour
}
```

`pass` tells Varnish not to look into its cache, it will always fetch the content from the backend.

Comment: how can I know or check sir, if example.com was the only url cache by varnish and others are not? thank you for the responds sir.

Comment: You can run varnishlog on your server while you are doing the request. You'll see if your requests are HIT  (cached), MISS (looked up in cache and not found) or PASS (not looked up in cache). Plus, you should read the basics from varnish book. It's worth it.

Comment: how about sir. if I want to cache is external server, not the localhost domains.

Comment: It's a weird behaviour you request but you can do what you want with the vcl logic, just change the condition of the `ìf` to your liking. You can use logical operators like  `!`, `==`, `&&`, `||` and `~` which stands for a regex

Comment: this is my latest update sir.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100313/varnish-4-remote-cache