# Unable to login through Varnish 4 cache

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I need some help. How can I do this in new version? since vcl_fetch is old and it is not accepeed now in Varnish 4.

```
sub vcl_fetch{
if (beresp.http.set-cookie ~ "sessionid" || beresp.http.set-cookie ~ "csrftoken") {
           return (pass);
         } else {
               return (deliver);
         }
}
```

Comment: vcl_fetch is vcl_backend_response in v4, check this url https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

Vcl_fetch has been moved to vcl_backend_response.

That said it's not a good idea to return pass from vcl_backend_response.
You should rewrite your `return (pass)` to

```
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
set beresp.ttl = 120s;
return (deliver);
```

Your whole vcl_backend_response should look like the following

```
sub vcl_fetch{
if (beresp.http.set-cookie ~ "sessionid" || beresp.http.set-cookie ~ "csrftoken") {
  set beresp.uncacheable = true;
  set beresp.ttl = 120s;
  return (deliver);
     } else {
           set beresp.ttl = 10s;
           set beresp.grace = 1h;
     }
```

}

Comment: hi sir.. my 
sub vcl_backend_response {
   set beresp.ttl = 10s;
   set beresp.grace = 1h;
}

and this is my problem 
it cant login and other main page has response MISS but its js, css, and image is already HIT

Comment: i updated it to 

sub vcl_backend_response {

if (beresp.http.set-cookie ~ "sessionid" || beresp.http.set-cookie ~ "csrftoken"){
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
set beresp.ttl = 120s;
return (deliver);
}
still the same problem

Comment: When you say you "cannot login" can you go more into details which requests failed or are cached when they shouldn't ?

Comment: this is the case sir.
example.com/admin 
in firebug, example.com/admin is MISS while the js css image is HIT , y is example.com/admin is MISS, and with that when I test to login , POST is ISS and has this info Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.

Comment: Il need more détails. Which requests?

Comment: this is the case sir. example.com/admin in firebug, example.com/admin is MISS while the js css image is HIT , y is example.com/admin is MISS, and with that, when I test to login , POST is MISS and has this info (warning sign) "Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen"

Comment: GET admin : Response Headers
Via 
1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache 
MISS
X-Frame-Options 
SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By 
PleskLin
X-Varnish 
262174

Comment: GET logo.gif : Response Headers Server 
Apache
Via 
1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache 
HIT
X-Powered-By 
PleskLin
X-Varnish 
360449 65541

Comment: When Logging In 
POST admin : 
Via 
1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache 
MISS
X-Frame-Options 
SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By 
PleskLin
X-Varnish 
262191

Comment: From what you've shared the login sees to work. They miss and thanks what we want. Do you want the whole /admin/ part to not be cached? If that's the case you should specify it in the vcl_recv sub. The same goes for loggd users requests. If you don't want them cached you need to specify it in the vcl_recv (checking on the cookie header).

Comment: how can I do that in vcl_recv sir ? yes i dont want to cache the admin, since it is not necessary right. only the public where they order .

Comment: since, I can login in public (frontend) for costumer with varnish, only this admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126188/discussion-between-rkevx21-and-benjamin-baumann).